# Using View Pager For custom Gallery view without Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I am creating an app in which i am using custom gallery view (without Gallery as it is deprecated). I am using View Pager for Horizontal scroll now after overriding onMeasure() still getting extra height in view my code snippet is below

```
     @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) 
            == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

    if(wrapHeight) {

        int width = getMeasuredWidth(), height = getMeasuredHeight();

        // Use the previously measured width but simplify the calculations
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        /* If the pager actually has any children, take the first child's 
         * height and call that our own */ 
        if(getChildCount() > 0) {
            View firstChild = getChildAt(0);

            /* The child was previously measured with exactly the full height.
             * Allow it to wrap this time around. */
            firstChild.measure(widthMeasureSpec, 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

            height = firstChild.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```